# Доступ к сайте в VirtualBox на Сentos

Tags: virtualbox, centos7

Не могу получить доступ к сайту запущенному на Centos в VirtualBox. Как можно понять в чем проблема ? Ping по ip адресу, который назначен сетевому адаптеру virtual box пингуется, но сайт не открывается. Можно ли как-то продиагностировать проблему ? Может есть какой-нибудь инструмент для таких вещей? Спасибо.

Comment: Вы откуда хотите получить доступ к сайту? это не сказали в вопросе?

Comment: Доступ хотел получить из локальной сети машины хоста. Не думал что это важно поэтому не написал.

Comment: В общем плане если хотите из одного места (компьютера или виртуалки) получить доступ к сайту (который на другом), и если все они в одной подсети. то надо в том компьютерe в хостах написать `ip` того компьютера на котором лежит сайт. пример - `192.168.8.34 www.mysite.com`

Comment: Спасибо за ваш комментарий,это я знаю, я так и делал, и если обратите внимание на вопрос, там указано что ping проходит. Однако получить ответ от сервера не получалось, что и навело на мысль что что-то блокирует доступ либо в virtual box либо в гостевой ОС.

Comment: Есть, но ведь проблема уже решена, доступ я уже получил, зачем искать дальше, если уже все работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в SELinux. Я его просто отключил, конечно решение временное, сейчас мне нужно просто протестировать свой сайт.